# Insert a point into a mysql column

Tags: mysql, geometry

I'm trying to insert a point into a mysql column. However, when I try to retrieve the point, it says just "?? ??"

```
CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY);
ALTER TABLE geom ADD pt POINT;
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'));
```

The lines above are the ones that I use to create the table and to insert the point.

When I perform `SELECT * FROM GEOM`, I got the result below
[image]
If you pay attention, these lines are the same available here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

I spent some hours on this problem and I see many questions here about this issue. None of them helped me to solve the problem. If you know something, please tell me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try: `SELECT ST_AsText(pt)` instead.

Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html

Comment: Does JDBC support this kind of command? Because I need to retrieve the points to use them in a Vector 2d class I'm working on.

Comment: Should be, it looks like a MySQL function so I'd guess it should work regardless of the interface.